# UK visit visa refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, proof-of-ties

UK visit visa refusal

I was recently denied a visit visa and I would like to re apply.

The visa was denied because I had stated I had no income or savings, whilst I had also stated In the application I had a monthly expenditure of x amount. so that raiseD concerns on how I could spend that monthly without an income or savings. I do however get an allowance in cash from my mother Monthly but I didn’t in effect at the time realize I had to state that as an income.

Also: my entire trip is being sponsored for by my spouse and father My in law (Accommodation,food etc..) and the Only cost I will bare is the purchase of a return [image]air ticket, of which (as I also did on my last successful visa application) I was given funds by my mother for this and I went on and opened A bank account and My mother wired The funds into my personal bank account directly from hers. However my mothers bank statementS that I provided seemed to have missed the two pages that showed this money transfer/transaction  and so the statement couldn’t prove origin of funds.

I have since collected my mother’s complete bank statement, and I will this time state in my application the allowance I get to correspond with my monthly expenditure.

am open to all thoughts, ideas and recommendations.

How best can I address these issues in my re application?

Comment: Well yes and no

Comment: " my entire trip is being sponsored for by my spouse". So why do you need your mother statements? Could you review your question, and try to clarify. In any case, money transfer are often seen as very bad. So you should not apply for some months (and I would not do it, also not to seems desperate to entry in UK).

Comment: You could try paying your cash allowance into your bank account for several months before you reapply. However, ‘unemployed, wishing to visit spouse already in the UK’ is a huge red flag; you need to figure out what ties to your country of residence you can show that would be a compelling reason for you to leave at the end of your proposed visit (see V 4.2 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)

Comment: You’re likely to be refused again.